# How to navigate html table (with tbody) cells by pressing buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a html table with few buttons(up,down,right and left) to allow user navigate the table cells by pressing each one. At this moment the right and left button doesn't function at all and only up and down works some times work if you press it many times!(The down button when it reaches the the last row if user clicks down button again the highlight disappears instead of staying on the last row!) . Could an expert tell me how to fix this broken code.Thanks in advance.

**Note:** i want the focus be on javascript:doit when highlight moves across the cells because i want to add another button so user by clicking that it calls the doit functio!n

[image]

Here is the broken code in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yubeLjnx/

full code:

```
<head>

<style>

table td{
  border:1px solid grey;
  padding:10px;
}

.hilighted {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 1px;
}

button.up {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
button.down {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var TableHilighter = function(table, selected) {
    this.table = $(table);
    this.rows = this.table.find('tr').length;
    this.cols = this.table.find('tr').first().find('td').length;
    this.selected = (typeof selected === 'undefined') ? [1, 1] : selected;

    // Hilight our row on initialization
    this.hilight();
  };

  TableHilighter.prototype = {
    "hilight": function(cell) {
      if (typeof cell === 'undefined') {
        cell = this.selected;
      }
      // Clear all hilighted cells
      this.table.find('td').removeClass('hilighted');

      // First find the row, then find the col, and add the .hilighted class
      this.table.find('tr:nth-child(' + this.selected[1] + ')').find('td:nth-child(' + this.selected[0] + ')').addClass('hilighted');
    },
    "move": function(dir) {
      switch (dir) {
        case 'up':
          this._up();
          break;
        case 'down':
          this._down();
          break;
        case 'left':
          this._left();
          break;
        case 'right':
          this._right();
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      this.hilight();
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_left": function() {
      if (this._x() > 1) {
        this._x(this._x() - 1);
      }
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_right": function() {
      if (this._x() < this.cols) {
        this._x(this._x() + 1);
      }
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_up": function() {
      if (this._y() > 1) {
        this._y(this._y() - 1);
      }
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_down": function() {
      if (this._y() < this.rows) {
        this._y(this._y() + 1);
      }
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_x": function(x) {
      if (typeof x === 'undefined') {
        return this.selected[0];
      } else {
        this.selected[0] = x;
        return this.selected[0];
      }
    },
    "_y": function(y) {
      if (typeof y === 'undefined') {
        return this.selected[1];
      } else {
        this.selected[1] = y;
        return this.selected[1];
      }
    }
  };

  // Initialize our TableHilighter
  var my_table = new TableHilighter('table');

  // Add button event handlers
  $('.up').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    my_table.move('up');
  });

  $('.down').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    my_table.move('down');
  });

  $('.left').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    my_table.move('left');
  });

  $('.right').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    my_table.move('right');
  });
});


</script>
</head>

<body>


<button class="up">Up</button>

<div>
    <button class="left">Left</button>
    <button class="right">Right</button>
</div>

<button class="down">Down</button>


<div class="scroller">

<div id="myDiv" style="display: visiable;">  

<table id="demo" style="display: visible;" cellspacing="0" border="1">
<thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Item#</th>
      <th>Logo</th>
      </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<tr>
<td class="hilighted">
<div class="image">
<a href="javascript:doit('1')">
<img src="http://mywebsite/images/1/thumb.jpg" alt="">Title 1 
</a>
</div>
</td>



<td>
<div class="image">
<a href="javascript:doit('2')">
<img src="http://mywebsite/images/2/thumb.jpg" alt="">Title 2
</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div class="image">
<a href="javascript:doit('3')">
<img src="http://mywebsite/images/3/thumb.jpg"  alt="">Title 3
</a>
</div>
</td>



<td>
<div class="image">
<a href="javascript:doit('4')">
<img src="http://mywebsite/images/4/thumb.jpg" alt="">Title 4
</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<div class="image">
<a href="javascript:doit('5')">
<img src="http://mywebsite/images/5/thumb.jpg" alt="">Title 5
</a>
</div>
</td>



<td>
<div class="image">
<a href="javascript:doit('6')">
<img src="http://mywebsite/images/6/thumb.jpg"  alt="">Title 6
</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your test, see the comment :)
i have only changed two lines in ur  code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var TableHilighter = function(table, selected) {
    this.table = $(table) 
    this.rows = this.table.find("tbody").find('tr').length ;
    this.cols = this.table.find("tbody").find('tr').first().find('td').length ;// thead dose not containe td thats why you get -1 on cols :)
    this.selected = (typeof selected === 'undefined') ? [1, 1] : selected;

    // Hilight our row on initialization
    this.hilight();
  };

  TableHilighter.prototype = {
    "hilight": function(cell) {
      if (typeof cell === 'undefined') {
        cell = this.selected;
      }
      // Clear all hilighted cells
      this.table.find('td').removeClass('hilighted');
      
      // First find the row, then find the col, and add the .hilighted class
      this.table.find('tr:nth-child(' + this.selected[1] + ')').find('td:nth-child(' + this.selected[0] + ')').addClass('hilighted');
    },
    "move": function(dir, v) {
      switch (dir) {
        case 'up':
          this._up();
          break;
        case 'down':
          this._down();
          break;
        case 'left':
          this._left();
          break;
        case 'right':
          this._right();
          break;
        case 'doit':
         this._doit(v);
         break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      this.hilight();
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_doit" : function(selected){

      // here i found the selected cell and row do what you want with them
     alert("value is " + selected);
    
    }, 
    "_left": function() {
      if (this._x() > 1) {
        this._x(this._x() - 1);
      }
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_right": function() {
      if (this._x() < this.cols) {
        this._x(this._x() + 1);
      }
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_up": function() {
      if (this._y() > 1) {
        this._y(this._y() - 1);
      }
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_down": function() {
      if (this._y() < this.rows) {
        this._y(this._y() + 1);
      }
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_x": function(x) {
      if (typeof x === 'undefined') {
        return this.selected[0];
      } else {
        this.selected[0] = x;
        return this.selected[0];
      }
    },
    "_y": function(y) {
      if (typeof y === 'undefined') {
        return this.selected[1];
      } else {
        this.selected[1] = y;
        return this.selected[1];
      }
    }
  };
  
  // Initialize our TableHilighter
  var my_table = new TableHilighter('table');
  
  // Add button event handlers
  $('.up').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    my_table.move('up');
  });
  
  $('.down').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    my_table.move('down');
  });
  
  $('.left').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    my_table.move('left');
  });
  
  $('.right').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    my_table.move('right');
  });
  
  $('.doit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     var selectedCel = my_table.table.find("tbody").find('td.hilighted');
     var selectedRow = selectedCel.parent();
     var row = selectedRow.index();
     var cell = selectedCel.index();
     var value = ((row * selectedRow.find("td").length) + cell) +1;
     
    my_table.move('doit', value);
  });
  
});
```

```css
table td{
  border:1px solid grey;
  padding:10px;
}

.hilighted {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 1px;
}

button.up {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
button.down {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="up">Up</button>

<div>
    <button class="left">Left</button>
    <button class="right">Right</button>
</div>

<button class="down">Down</button>

<button class='doit'>click highlighed cell</button>

<div class="scroller">

<div id="myDiv" style="display: visiable;">  

<table id="demo" style="display: visible;" cellspacing="0" border="1">

<thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Item#</th>
      <th>Logo</th>
      </tr>
</thead>
  
<tbody>

<tr>
<td class="hilighted">
<div class="image">
<a href="javascript:doit('1')">
<img src="http://mywebsite/images/1/thumb.jpg" alt="">Title 1 
</a>
</div>
</td>



<td>
<div class="image">
<a href="javascript:doit('2')">
<img src="http://mywebsite/images/2/thumb.jpg" alt="">Title 2
</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div class="image">
<a href="javascript:doit('3')">
<img src="http://mywebsite/images/3/thumb.jpg"  alt="">Title 3
</a>
</div>
</td>



<td>
<div class="image">
<a href="javascript:doit('4')">
<img src="http://mywebsite/images/4/thumb.jpg" alt="">Title 4
</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<div class="image">
<a href="javascript:doit('5')">
<img src="http://mywebsite/images/5/thumb.jpg" alt="">Title 5
</a>
</div>
</td>



<td>
<div class="image">
<a href="javascript:doit('6')">
<img src="http://mywebsite/images/6/thumb.jpg"  alt="">Title 6
</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning which lines needed to be corrected .I am planning to add another button called "click highlighed cell" so once user click on that button it should fire the javascript:doit on that cell ? how i can achieve that ?

Comment: Thanks .Is it possible to get value of doit passing it to doit function?( doit('4') )

Comment: i have updated my answer :) i have calculated the value instead of getting it from the link. var value = ((row * selectedRow.find("td").length) + cell) +1;

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you get the total of tr (4) & td (6) and that will not stop right and down when you add 1 every time .

Try the following :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var TableHilighter = function(table, selected) {
    this.table = $(table);
    this.rows = $( "table tr" ).length;
    this.cols = $( "table tr td" ).length;
    this.selected = (typeof selected === 'undefined') ? [1, 1] : selected;
    
    // Hilight our row on initialization
    this.hilight();
  };

  TableHilighter.prototype = {
    "hilight": function(cell) {
      if (typeof cell === 'undefined') {
        cell = this.selected;
      }
      // Clear all hilighted cells
      this.table.find('td').removeClass('hilighted');
      
      // First find the row, then find the col, and add the .hilighted class
      this.table.find('tr:nth-child(' + this.selected[1] + ')').find('td:nth-child(' + this.selected[0] + ')').addClass('hilighted');
    },
    "move": function(dir) {
      switch (dir) {
        case 'up':
          this._up();
          break;
        case 'down':
          this._down();
          break;
        case 'left':
          this._left();
          break;
        case 'right':
          this._right();
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      this.hilight();
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_left": function() {
      if (this._x() > 1) {
        this._x(this._x() - 1);
      }
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_right": function() {
      if (this._x() < (this.cols-4)) {
      
        this._x(this._x() + 1);
        }
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_up": function() {
      if (this._y() > 1) {
        this._y(this._y() - 1);
      }
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_down": function() {
      if (this._y() < (this.rows-1)) {
     
        this._y(this._y() + 1);
      }
      return this.selected;
    },
    "_x": function(x) {
      if (typeof x === 'undefined') {
        return this.selected[0];
      } else {
        this.selected[0] = x;
        return this.selected[0];
      }
    },
    "_y": function(y) {
      if (typeof y === 'undefined') {
        return this.selected[1];
      } else {
        this.selected[1] = y;
        return this.selected[1];
      }
    }
  };
  
  // Initialize our TableHilighter
  var my_table = new TableHilighter('table');
  
  // Add button event handlers
  $('.up').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    my_table.move('up');
  });
  
  $('.down').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    my_table.move('down');
  });
  
  $('.left').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    my_table.move('left');
  });
  
  $('.right').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    my_table.move('right');
  });
});
```

```css
table td{
  border:1px solid grey;
  padding:10px;
}
.hilighted {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 1px;
}

button.up {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
button.down {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="up">Up</button>

<div>
    <button class="left">Left</button>
    <button class="right">Right</button>
</div>

<button class="down">Down</button>

<div class="scroller">

<div id="myDiv" style="display: visiable;">  

<table id="demo" style="display: visible;" cellspacing="0" border="1">

<thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Item#</th>
      <th>Logo</th>
      </tr>
</thead>
  
<tbody>

<tr>
<td class="hilighted">
<div class="image">
<a href="javascript:doit('1')">
<img src="http://mywebsite/images/1/thumb.jpg" alt="">Title 1 
</a>
</div>
</td>



<td>
<div class="image">
<a href="javascript:doit('2')">
<img src="http://mywebsite/images/2/thumb.jpg" alt="">Title 2
</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div class="image">
<a href="javascript:doit('3')">
<img src="http://mywebsite/images/3/thumb.jpg"  alt="">Title 3
</a>
</div>
</td>



<td>
<div class="image">
<a href="javascript:doit('4')">
<img src="http://mywebsite/images/4/thumb.jpg" alt="">Title 4
</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<div class="image">
<a href="javascript:doit('5')">
<img src="http://mywebsite/images/5/thumb.jpg" alt="">Title 5
</a>
</div>
</td>



<td>
<div class="image">
<a href="javascript:doit('6')">
<img src="http://mywebsite/images/6/thumb.jpg"  alt="">Title 6
</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for replies. @Mohammed Elhag . Your correction is working well with short sample but since i am populating the table with data from ajax(300 cells) and by the time $(document).ready(function() runs the table is not finished populated completely and that causes the buttons not work well(also first cell fails to be highlighted)! How to fix that .Furthermore, i am planning to add another button called "click highlighed cell" so once user click on that button it should fire the javascript:doit on that cell ? how i can achieve that ?